# How can I count files by file type?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, directory

I have a Java program that goes over all the folders and files inside a given folder and it prints them.
The issues is that now I want to count all the files in the folder by their extension. How can I do that?

This is my code so far:

```
package ut5_3;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class UT5_3 {

    ArrayList<String> extensionArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> extensionArrayTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File directoryPath = new File("C://Users//Anima//Downloads//MiDir");
        File[] directoryContent = directoryPath.listFiles();
        UT5_3 prueba = new UT5_3();
        prueba.goOverDirectory(directoryContent);
    }

    public void goOverDirectory(File[] directoryContent) {
        
        for (File content : directoryContent) {

            if (content.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("===========================================");
                System.out.println("+" + content.getName());

                goOverDirectory(content.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.

            } else {
                String directoryName = content.getName();
                System.out.println("    -" + directoryName);
                String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(directoryName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've tried making two ArrayList. One to store all the extensions from all the files and another one to store the distinct extensions, but I got really confused and I didn't know how to continue with that idea.

If it is too complex, it'd be great if you could explain an easier way to do it too.
Thanks!

Comment: How comprehensive is this? Do you need a separate count of files by extension in each folder and subfolder, or do you want a general count of files by extension?

Comment: I posted a solution that I think will for you. Need to run on Java 8 or higher because it uses the Stream API.

Comment: Just a general count of files by extensions, yes. And well, the solution looks great, tho I'm a begginer so I'm not familiar at all wish streams, maps, collectors... But I'll work my way up there, ty ^^

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to store the count of all of the file extensions you see. Here is how I would approach it.

First initialize a map with a String as the key and int as the value, at the top of your class like so.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> extensions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then you can run this whenever you need to add an extension to the count.

```
String in = "exe";
if(extensions.containsKey(in)) 
    extensions.put(in, extensions.get(in) + 1);
else 
    extensions.put(in, 1);
```

If you want to retrieve the count, simply run `extensions.get(in)`.

If you didn't know already, a HashMap allows you to assign a `key` to a `value`. In this case, the `key` is the file extension and `value` is the count.

Good day

Comment: I don't think this even close to the answer.

Comment: op wanted to count file extensions. This is a way to do that.

Comment: @hfontanez I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: @JawadElFou quoting the OP "_The issues is that now I want to count all the files in the folder by their extension_". Count **ALL** the files by **THEIR** extension. Which means that you need to group all files by extension and provide a count of each grouping. Tell me what I didn't understand and how this code does exactly that?

Comment: Then instead of saving an int, just save an arraylist of files? if op specifies ill change mate

Comment: @Chspsa No, it is not. It is a terrible answer. If you have a directory with 100 different extensions, how is this solution going to solve that problem?

Comment: Well, I barely understand anything of that code, but it works for what I'm trying to do. Ty ^^

Comment: @hfontanez Result of this Answer is a structure that maps extension(string) to number of occurences(int). What tells you that OP want's more than that?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 or higher is actually not too difficult. First, you need to collect the items. Then, you need to group them by extension and create a map of extensions with the count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path start = Paths.get("C:/Users/Hector/Documents");

    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(start)){
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (!Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                fileNames.add(entry.getFileName().toString());// add file name in to name list
            }
        }
    }

    fileNames.stream().map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fileName -> fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1)))
            .entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                System.out.println("File extension: " + entry.getKey() + ", Count: " + entry.getValue().size());
            });
}
```

For my "Documents" directory
[image]

Produced the following output

```
File extension: zargo~, Count: 3
File extension: txt, Count: 1
File extension: exe, Count: 1
File extension: pdf, Count: 3
File extension: ini, Count: 1
File extension: log, Count: 1
File extension: svg, Count: 1
File extension: zargo, Count: 3
File extension: lnk, Count: 1
```

The reason why I chose this solution over using `Files.walk()` is because this method can throw an `AccessDeniedException` which is problematic when you need to traverse different folders. However, if you can control access to a folder by calling `canRead()` method on the file object, then you could use it. I personally don't like it and many Java developers have issue with that function.

You could modify by adding it to a function that could be called recursively if the current path is a directory. Since the OP requirement is unclear if the count has to be for a given folder or the folder and all subfolders, I decided to just show the count for the current folder.

One last observation, when collecting the extensions, notice that I pass to the `substring` function to start from the last index of the period character. This is important to capture the real extension for files with multiple periods in the name. For example: `Setup.x64.en-US_ProPlusRetail_RDD8N-JF2VC-W7CC6-TVXJC-3YF3D_TX_PR_act_1_OFFICE_13.exe`. In a file, the extension always starts after the last period.

Comment: `Files.walk` was my first thought, when I sow this question. Well done.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko also mine and pretty much every example there is out there for this type of problem. However, if you look under the surface, there is a lot of criticism as well. Because of this exception, you can't traverse full directory trees if the exception is thrown.